# Modifying existing XML file present on sdcard

Tags: android, xml

I have been working on android for about 4 months, i am working on a simple application to download a xml file placed on local server to the sdcard. I have done this part successfully, now i want to edit the data present in that xml. To get a more clear picture here is a sample code of my xml file ...

```
<seekbar>
    <value>
           50
    </value>
</seekbar>
```

now am reading the value 50 by xml parsing and updating the value of seekbar as 50. Nowi change the value of seekbar to 100 through GUI. So when i click on save button i want that the value 50 should be replaced by 100 in the xml present in the sdcard. I have learnt about the sdcard permission  but i am not getting about how to go for this modifying part.. Will i have to parse the whole xml again...??? Please help guys....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the xml into a DOM Object. modify the value or value node and write the new DOM object back to the file.

Comment: Thank you Rajdeep for the answer but will the creation of DOM object solve the problem or will i have to use SAX parser for it.

Comment: SAX is generally used for read only scenarios, for modifying xml you need DOM